# What does mean the term “regression” in the context “Fixed regressions”?

Tags: pandas

In almost all releases of pandas there is in *Documentation / Release notes* the part “[Fixed regressions](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v1.2.2.html#fixed-regressions)”, where all items begin with the words *“Fixed regression...”*, e.g.

> Fixed regression in read_excel() that caused it to raise AttributeError when checking version of older xlrd versions (GH38955)

What does in mean the term *“regression”* in this context?
Why fixed regressions are not included in the (next) part “Bug fixes”?

Comment: In software development, a "regression" is when you break something that used to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're a special kind of bug fix.

For example, if a new feature is introduced in version X, it (inadvertently) breaks in version Y and version Z fixes it, that's "fixing a regression".

Answer (score 1):

Its related to the concept of [Regression testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_testing)

**From the wiki** :

> Regression testing is re-running functional and non-functional tests
> to ensure that previously developed and tested software still performs
> after a change If not, that would be called a regression. Changes that
> may require regression testing include bug fixes, software
> enhancements, configuration changes, and even substitution of
> electronic components.